# Allowing multiple records in category to submit to listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want multiple (an array of...) category_id's to be saved to each listing, if more than one are chosen.  Below is how everything is set up, including how categories work alongside with listings.

Category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :category
  has_many :listings
```

Listing model:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, required: false
  attr_accessor :new_category_name
  before_save :create_category_from_name

  # has_many :categories
```

Scheme (for categories and listings):

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "image"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_listings_on_category_id"
  end
```

I then have the categories defined within the seed.rb and then rails db:seed to input them when i need to add them.

Listing Controller for New:

```
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
    @categories = Category.all

    3.times do
      @listing.categories.build
    end


  end
```

Form Views for creating a Listing (in brief):

```
<%= form_with(model: listing, local: true) do |form| %>

<%= form.label "Choose Up to 3 Categories (1 required)"%>

  <div class="space">
    <%= form.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select a Category" %>
    <%= form.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select a Category" %>
    <%= form.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select a Category" %>
  </div>

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  <%= form.label "Choose Up to 3 Categories (1 required)"%>

    <div class="space">
  <% form.fields_for :category_id do |c| %>
    <%= c.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select a Category" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <% form.fields_for :category_id do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :category_id %>
    <% end %>

    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Between the "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" are my attempts to testing it.  They don't even show up within the form though, which I don't know why.

When I use the first  "form.select :category_id" which brings up 3 drop downs, only the last selected drop down saves.  If i select 3 separate categories, only the last one picked will save.  I want to be able to have multiple categories chosen for each listing.

How do i allow multiple categories to be saved when creating a new listing? Whether a dropdown, checkboxes, etc.  Just need the possibility of more than one to save to one listing, if more than one are chosen by the user.

**UPDATE:**

Schema:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "categories_listings", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "category_id", null: false
    t.integer "listing_id", null: false
  end
```

View form:

```
<%= form.select :category_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select a Category", :multiple => true %>
```

Control params:

```
params.require(:listing).permit(:attr1, :name, :description, :price, :image, :category_id, category_ids: [])
```

Models:

```
    Category
      has_and_belongs_to_many :listings


Listing

belongs_to :category, required: false
  belongs_to :categories_listings, required: false
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thx fixed it to relevant only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use the first "form.select :category_id" which brings up 3 drop
>   downs, only the last selected drop down saves. If i select 3 separate
>   categories, only the last one picked will save. I want to be able to
>   have multiple categories chosen for each listing.

Ofcourse, you are having three **same dropdowns** for the **same attribute** and it will just picks the last dropdown's selected value and passes it to the `params`.

You need to set it as **one dropdown** and allow **multiple selections** on it like so

```
<%= form.select :category_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select a Category", :multiple => true %>
```

Notice the changes `:category_ids` and `:multiple => true`. `:category_ids` is a method([`collection_singular_ids`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)) that ships for *many-to-many* associations which will be used by Rails under the hood to **create entries for the joined table**.

`:multiple => true` allows you to select more than one option and pass those `ids` as array. For instance like this `category_ids: ["1","2","3"]`

Now coming to your controller code, you **shouldn't be building the listings** for categories as your approach is different. Change you new method to below

```
def new
  @listing = Listing.new
end
```

It is also not necessary to have `@categories = Category.all` as you are explicitly calling `Category.all` in the `select`

And finally whitelist `category_ids` in the `listing_params` like so

```
params.require(:listing).permit(:attr1, .... category_ids: [])
```

> Between the "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" are my attempts to testing it.
>   They don't even show up within the form though, which I don't know
>   why.

Well, you are messing up with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and as well with [`fields_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for). Read on!

**Note:**

Also as **@IIya Konyukhov** mentioned, your schema looks different for a *HABTM* association. You should alter your schema for to fit the needs of your approach to work.

**Update #1**

> I'm using categories as a way to search through listings. so i want,
>   when creating a listing, to be able to choose multiple categories to
>   go along with the listing. and categories will be pre-defined.

The above mentioned approach should fit your need, but there are more tweaks need to be done in  your code to make it work.

1) The associations in `Category` model are flawed. You need to change `has_many :listings` to `has_and_belongs_to_many :listings`

2) Remove `validates_uniqueness_of :category` from the Category model as it is not valid.

3) Remove `category_id` from `listings` table

4) Generate a HABTM joined-table for `listings` and `categories` as below

```
rails generate migration CreateJoinTableCategoryListing category listing
```

Now upon saving the listing, rails under the hood will create entries for `categories_listings` which will be correct for above mentioned approach.

> Although, new ones will/should be able to be added by admins (not by
>   users) to then have the ability to add the category to an existing or
>   new listing

This can also be done by the same approach as above for to create a new listing with existing categories. And just render the edit form of the listing to add an existing category for that existed listing. You just need to make sure these routes are different and can only be accessed by admins.

**Update #2:**

You need to remove your current associations in `Listing` model and add the following code in it.

```
#listing.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

And also remove `category_id` from the params list. Just keep `category_ids: []`

```
params.require(:listing).permit(:attr1, :name, :description, :price, :image, category_ids: [])
```

Comment: How should i then define my categories the best way.  I am currently using the seed.rb and inputing that way (which is why i use  validates_uniqueness_of :category so i dont create duplicates when adding new ones).

Comment: @uno It depends on what you want to do? Do you want to create listings along with categories, then you should use accepts_nested_attributes_for along with fields_for. Or if you want to create listing for an existing category, then try my approach. And FYI this `validates_uniqueness_of :category` invalid

Comment: I'm using categories as a way to search through listings.  so i want, when creating a listing, to be able to choose multiple categories to go along with the listing.  and categories will be pre-defined.  although, new ones will/should be able to be added by admins (not by users) to then have the ability to add the category to an existing or new listing.  hope that explains it.  im not exactly sure if im doing this correctly

Comment: i updated my code in the original post.  The entries are saving but the categories_listings table nothing saves into it.  Is there a certain way I need to set up my form to enter into it or?

Comment: I got an error: "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)" Also, i updated my category.rb assume you meant to update my category.rb model to what you said? and when this does work, i am worried about what if only 1 category gets entered, because i want to allow 1 - 5 categories per listing.  also concerned with the "mutliple => true" because i also tried using a checkbox system but that also wouldn't work

Comment: @uno My bad! updated the answer. If only one category is selected then only one entry will be created in categories_listings table. :multiple => true lets you to select multiple categories from the dropdown. If you want that with checkboxes, use [`check_box`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) helper with `:multiple => true`  or use [`collection_check_boxes`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)

Comment: Looks like i'm receiving the error still : "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)"  my params are:: "  params.require(:listing).permit(:attr1, :name, :description, :price, :image, :category_ids [])"

Comment: 140, on the params.requre line.  Here's the CMD: app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:140:in `[]'
app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:140:in `listing_params'
app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:94:in `create'

Comment: @uno You should change  `:category_ids []` to  `:category_ids => []` or  `category_ids: []`

Answer (score 0):

Your data relationship seems to be incorrect. Take a look:

- `Category` model validates uniqueness of `category`. But there is no field category in categories table. It seems name should be used instead.
- `Listing` model `has and belongs to many` `categories`. For Rails it means that these 2 tables are connected via 3rd table, `categories_listings`, which holds `category_id` and `listing_id`. But your database schema is different - in your tables `category_id` belongs to `listings` table, which matches [`Category` model `has many` `listings`] association. There is a contradiction.

I would consider data model as a basis for the whole application. Having the correct data model, writing code for controllers and views becomes transparent and obvious. Fix your data model first and use [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for saving associated models.

Comment: For the "  validates_uniqueness_of :category " if i don't have this,the categories will keep duplicating the cateogires from the seed.rb on import.  Is there a better way to be creating categories, such as something like "CATEGORY = %w{ cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 }" and call it that way? or maybe something else you know would be better practice?

Comment: i fixed my models to.. category.rb to has_many :listings.... and listings.rb to   belongs_to :category, required: false
Is that the rigth way?

Answer (score 0):

[has_and_belongs_to_many](https://railsguide.org/rails/ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) just supports array of nested parameters 
you should permit parameters like this `params.require(:listing).permit(:attr, ..., category_ids: [])`
then change on form with this code

```
<%= form.select :category_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select Categories", multiple: true %>
```