# How to use a form to add to both joined tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a joined table but looking for a way to input the information from a form into both tables, or have it work in general:

My schema:

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "categories_listings", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "category_id", null: false
    t.integer "listing_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "image"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

Models:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :listings
end

Listing < ApplicationRecord    
  belongs_to :category, required: false
  belongs_to :categories_listings, required: false
end
```

Views

```
<%= form_with(model: listing, local: true) do |form| %>
...
  <div class="space">
    <%= form.select :category_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select a Category", :multiple => true %>
  </div>
...
```

Before i joined the tables, I had it working with a categories element (i believe thats the right term) within the listing tables that was attached to a categories table... You can see my previous post on SO where I was suggested to do this: [Allowing multiple records in category to submit to listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865065/allowing-multiple-records-in-category-to-submit-to-listing/52869374#52869374)

When i click submit, nothing enters into the categories_listings tables.  Suggestions on how I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The associations in your `Listing` model are wrong. It should be just

```
Listing < ApplicationRecord    
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

I suggest you to read [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

Comment: Lol, it's me again.  I created this earlier from not being patient lol.  here's more sheckles! :)

Comment: for anyone stumbling across this post, here is the post indepth where Pavan helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/92692535

Comment: Although, I am wondering how to cap the entries at 5 on the parameter side.  I do know i can limit the checkmarks with javascript